# Why am I getting error "fatal: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git' is outside the repository" when I run "git reset --hard ~1" from within the repository?

Tags: git, mingw32, git-reset

I'm running SourceTree on Windows 7 and when I open the MINGW32 command prompt from within the respository folder (at C:\DEV\Shayne\Quarks) and try to delete the last commit by entering the command `git reset --hard ~1` I get the error `fatal: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git' is outside the repository`. The title bar of the command prompt reads `MINGW32:c/DEV/Shayne/Quarks`. I can't find any answers on Google and I've successfully run this command on this machine in the recent past. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure , git is initialized in this directory ?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure git is initialized in this directory. I have been using the same directory quite a lot in the last few months. I even tried it in another git repository and I get the same error.

Comment: So can you name the root directory where .git resides ? The error is because of that only. Say git is in "/home/user/here" and you do some git add operation like "git add /home/user/somefile-that-lies-here.txt

You will get this error.

Comment: Can you paste the output of your PATH variable ? I think its not configured properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are typing a bad command. You want to type

```
git reset --hard head~1
```

I have no idea why git reports this error when you type just `~1`, but it does.

Update:

This appears to happen because of [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

Comment: Oops. I feel like an idiot for forgetting to add the "HEAD" bit.

Comment: I'll bet this question gets a reasonable amount of traffic from other people doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Good one.  This is Git's least helpful error message